# Change definition of child class when parent is hovered in SCSS

Tags: sass

Trying to toggle the background and font colors on children in a div when the whole dive is hovered using SCSS, basically modifying classes within a hovered div is what I am after,  but in a SCSSy way.

I know I can simply use the complete name of the classes under &:hover, but I am trying to do it using the &__ notation and apparently this is not working for me, seemingly need to select the parent of the hover selector somehow, but haven't been able to figure it out yet.

```
.career_preview {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(170deg, white 82%, black 82.6%);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 20px;
    &__title {
        color: black;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    &__action {
        color: white;
        padding: 0 20px 10px 210px;
    }
    &__points {
        display: none;
    }
    &:hover {
        background-image: linear-gradient(170deg, black 82%, white 82.6%);
        &__title {
            display: none;        
        }
        &__action {
            color: black;
        }
        &__points {
            display: none;
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this structure:

```
.career_preview {
    &:hover {
        &__title {
            display: none;        
        }
    }
}
```

generates this selector:

```
.career_preview:hover__title {
  display: none;
}
```

Because "&" works by concatenating the parent selector with the rest:

First you have `.career_preview`, then `&:hover` gets converted to `.career_preview`+`:hover` and that's the new value for `&`. Now `&__title` uses `.career_preview:hover` and appends `__title` so you have: `.career_preview:hover`+`__title`.

Read more here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector

One way to solve this is to do something like this:

```
.career_preview {
    &:hover {
      background-image: "...";
    }
    &:hover & {
        &__title {
            display: none;        
        }
    }
}
```

Note the extra `&:over &` selector, that is converted to `.career_preview:hover .career_preview` for it's children, so `&__title` is now converted to `.career_preview:hover .career_preview`+`__title`

Comment: This answer is what I am looking for, but people may skip this topic because the title is not linked to key word that they use, for me a newbie SCSS, I use "how to chain children class after hover"

Answer (score 0):

This was the right approach after a bit of playing, seems obvious.

```
  &:hover {
        background-image: linear-gradient(170deg, black 82%, white 82.6%);
        .career_preview__title {
            display: none;        
        }
        .career_preview__action {
            color: black;
        }
        .career_preview__points {
            color: white;
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
.career_preview {
  &:hover {
    &__title {
      // some rules
    }
  }
}
```

will compile to: `.career_preview:hover__title`, because `&` join every part into selector.

You can use variable to simplify your code and fix this problem. For example:

```
.career_preview {
  $that: '.career_preview';

  &__title {
    // some rules
  }

  &:hover {
    #{$that}__title {
      // some rules
    }
  }
}
```